# Subdomain does not tail directory on nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain, rewrite

I'm trying to make the subdomain work when accessing to `dev.domain.com`, it should tail to the `/var/www/domain.com/www/dev` where `/var/www/domain.com/www/` is the root of `domain.com`. When I access to `dev.domain.com` it lands me to the root page of `domain.com`.

This is my configuration file for `domain.com` in `sites-enabled`:

```
server {

    server_name     *.domain.com domain.com;
    root            /var/www/domain.com/www;
    index           index.php index.htm index.html;
    error_page      404 /404.html;
    error_page      500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    access_log      /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/domain.com/logs/errors.log;

    # subdomain rewrites
    if ($host !~* ^www\.domain\.com$) {}
    if ($host ~* ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$) {
        set $auto_subdomain $1;
    }
    if (-d /var/www//www/$auto_subdomain) {}
    if (-f /var/www//www/$auto_subdomain$uri) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$auto_subdomain$uri;
        break;
    }

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /dev {
        auth_basic            "Development";
        auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/domain.com/www/dev/authfile;
    }
}
```

I also need it to be aware with `www.domain.com` that it should not look for the `www` directory in the root of `/var/www/domain.com/www/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the procedure in the last few commands here:

http://www.idolbin.com/blog/server-management/vps-setup-guide/configure-domains-and-subdomains-in-your-vps-running-nginx/

You'll find some little changes in configuration to the following config is suggested:

http://www.idolbin.com/blog/server-management/vps-setup-guide/setup-nginx-web-server-not-apache-on-ubuntu-10-04/

Answer (score 0):

According to [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html), you are using an ineffective way with multiple [`if`](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) directives. So, you should define a separate server block for `dev.example.com` and use [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) instead.

Comment: How can I write this?

Comment: Hello? I'm still asking about this.

Comment: No? You're not gonna help?

Comment: Both Nginx documentation site and ServerFault are full of correct configuration examples.